# Insert record of utf-8 character (Chinese, Arabic, Japanese.. etc) into GAE datastore programatically with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, character-encoding, google-cloud-datastore

I just want to build simple UI translation built in GAE (using python SDK).

```
def add_translation(self, pid=None):
    trans = Translation()
    trans.tlang = db.Key("agtwaW1kZXNpZ25lcnITCxILQXBwTGFuZ3VhZ2UY8aIEDA")
    trans.ttype = "UI"
    trans.transid = "ui-about"
    trans.content = "关于我们"
    trans.put()
```

this is resulting encoding error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to encode the correct insert content with unicode(utf-8) character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using the `u` notation:

```
>>> s=u"关于我们"
>>> print s
关于我们
```

Or explicitly, stating the encoding:

```
>>> s=unicode('אדם מתן', 'utf8')
>>> print s
אדם מתן
```

Read more at the [*Unicode HOWTO*](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) page in the python documentation site.